# I am trying to put a video(mp4) in the app but it is not playing

Tags: javascript, android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-videoview

```
package com.example.video_app;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.VideoView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button clk;
    VideoView Videov;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        clk=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        Videov=(VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView);

    }
    public void videoPlay(View v){
        String videoPath="android.resource:// com.example.video_app/"+R.raw.sv;//video path 
        Uri uri= Uri.parse(videoPath);
        Videov.setVideoURI(uri);
        Videov.start();//start

    }
}
```

I am new to android studio trying to build a simple app of video playing but the video is not playing cant get where the problem is.The video is not playing on emulator nor on my phone. i have tried all the codes mentioned in stackoverflow but could not find any solution... help to resolve this problem

Answer (score 0):

Check out [OnPreparedListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener). Call start() from inside that event, since then the file will be ready to be played.

Comment: "symbol
        String videoPath="android.resource://com.example.video_app/"+R.raw.sampleVideoIn3;
                                                                           ^
  symbol:   variable sampleVideoIn3"      This error is coming its telling me to register new file type association  n there is no video format file type the previous video i had registered as an image so it was not playing n all mp4 videos are set to that type only.How can i remove this thing

Comment: which type should I choose ??

Answer (score 0):

You haven't called `videoPlay()` method from any of the method,
Call `videoPlay()` method from `onCreate()` after `findViewById()` of video view.

and remove `View v` from `videoPlay()` method,i think it's useless.